# Bootstrap carousel with captions and thumbnails

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using a bootstrap snippet to make a carousel slider which has thumbnails and captions.

That is from http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-extended-320-compatible

I tried to make another carousel on the same page with changing the javascript.     `[http://jsfiddle.net/djotpxgb/][2]`

The first one works, but second one does not work properly.

If some one have the solution, please let me know.
Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple problem caused by placing two carousels on the same page with somewhat incorrect values for both to work correctly.

On every slide change, the text below the carousel is changed like this:

`var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
$('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-' + id).html());`

So, it takes the number from slide data attribute, and looks for **appropriate slide-content element**.

Please take a look what happens for the second carousel:

- First, in `$('#myCarousel2').on('slid.bs.carousel'...` it tries to take slide data like this:

  `var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');`

  which ends up with getting data from the **first carousel**; you can work around this easily changing the selector, like this for example:

  `var id = $('#myCarousel2').find('.item.active').data('slide-number');`
- Now, it will take the `data-slide-number` from these divs:

  `<div class="item" data-slide-number="6">
  <div class="item" data-slide-number="7">
  ...`
- Eventually, it will try to set the slide text to whatever is stored under the `#slide-content2-<id>` element, so it will look for #slide-content2-6 and so on
- But there are only `slide-content2-0` up to `slide-content2-3` elements, so it will try to set `undefined` as the `carousel-text2` html, which will simply fail

So concluding, you need to change the jQuery selector, and then make sure your `data-slide-number` in the second carousel slides will match anything in `slide-content2` elements.

[Here's an example how to solve this](http://jsfiddle.net/djotpxgb/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much wap300! It works perfectly.
var id = $('#myCarousel2').find('.item.active').data('slide-number');
This part seems the key for the solution. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Your thumbnail links have duplicate ID's, as an example, each carousel has a link with an ID of  "carousel-selector-1", etc.:

```
 <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=two"></a>
```